# Accessing local html floders for webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to know how do i use local folders in my webview to display the html content. So instead of using url can i use the local resource saved in the folder. Also if it is possible then it will worked once i publish the app on Google Playstore or it will be only visible for my local device? This is my of webview.

```
public class URLActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setInitialScale(0);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///assets/App/School.aspx");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                if (newProgress > 0) {
                    showProgressDialog("Please Wait...");
                }
                if (newProgress >= 100) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void showProgressDialog(final String msg) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (progress == null || !progress.isShowing()) {
                    progress = ProgressDialog.show(URLActivity.this, "", msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void hideProgressDialog() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (progress.isShowing())
                        progress.dismiss();
                } catch (Throwable e) {

                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: `School.aspx` --- you are not thinking to implement and run an ASP server on the target phone as well, are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend you should know this, you just cant use aspx format locally for mobile devices. You need a server to run aspx pages.